# Access Struts2 locale in Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: java, spring, struts2

Our application uses Struts2 Internalization and Spring `AbstractRoutingDataSource` for dynamic database changes. Changing the language, the corresponding language database should be selected.

So the below code makes the dynamic database selection using Spring `RoutingDataSource`.

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return LanguageContextHolder.getLanguagetype();
    }
}
```

Spring `RoutingDataSource` is working fine.

My problem is how to set the locale on change. Since it is stored in Struts2, I am not able  to access it in Spring.

I found the Spring MVC `org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder` would do this, but since we are using Struts2, how can I do the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 stores current locale in session with default key `WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE`. To access session inside your `RoutingDataSource` use `ActionContext.getContext().getSession()` method.

```
// ...

if (ActionContext.getContext() != null) {
  Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

  if (session != null && session.containsKey(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE)) {
    Locale locale = (Locale) session.get(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);
  }
}

// ...
```

Comment: @ Aleksandr - The routingdatasource is called at the time of server startup. So i am getting null pointer exception while calling ,  Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

Comment: @SivaranjaniD: Add additional check `ActionContext.getContext().getSession() != null` and assume default locale on server startup.

Comment: I tried that already, but still actioncontext is null always inside abstract routing datasource.. so it never goes inside the loop and changes the language

Comment: @SivaranjaniD: So what exactly is null actionContext or session? I've exactly same code inside `AbstractRoutingDataSource` and it is working fine. How do you test this? Running on server or unit testing?

Comment: ActionContext.getContext() is coming as null. I am running as a web application. Are you using the ThreadLocal implementation for Routing Datasource?

Comment: @SivaranjaniD: Hmmm... What do you mean a ThreadLocal implementation for datasource? How did you configured it? And yes this could be the problem with getting actionContext.

Comment: @SivaranjaniD: Put the code from my answer directly into the `RoutingDataSource`. Why do you need `LanguageContextHolder` at all? And if you do you can use it after you get locale from session.

Comment: Thanks Aleks for your support.. It is working now.. The ActionContext.getContext() was coming as null because i have not called any action before.

Answer (score 0):

In my example above "return LanguageContextHolder.getLanguagetype();" will return ThreadLocal type. And it is implemented as below.

```
public class LanguageContextHolder implements Serializable {    

private static ThreadLocal<LanguageType> languageType = new ThreadLocal<LanguageType>();

public static ThreadLocal<LanguageType> getLanguagetype() {
    return languageType;
}

public static void setLanguagetype(ThreadLocal<LanguageType> languagetype) {
    languageType = languagetype;
}

public static void clearLanguageType() {
    languageType.remove();
}
```

}